# Bridge JavaScript/Java in FF plugin

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to implement a connection between a FF plugin (using jetpack) and a java server which will handle all requests from the plugin. It seems I can stablish the connection but messages don't flow. I don't get anything coming from the plugin.

Here I post the codes:

JavaScript (client)

```js
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");

exports.main = function() {
try  {
    // At first, we need a nsISocketTransportService
    var transportService =  
        Cc["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
        .getService(Ci.nsISocketTransportService);  
       
    // Try to connect to localhost:2222
    var transport = transportService.createTransport(null, 0, "localhost", 2222, null);  

    var stream = transport.openInputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED,null,null); 
    var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream); 
        
    // Initialize
    instream.init(stream);
    var outstream = transport.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);
     
    // Write data
    var outputData = "bye";
    outstream.write(outputData, outputData.length);

    var dataListener = { 
        data : "", onStartRequest: function(request, context){},
         
        onStopRequest: function(request, context, status){
            instream.close();
            outstream.close();
            listener.finished(this.data); 
        }, 
        
        onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) { 
            this.data += instream.read(count); 
            console.log(this.data);             
        }, 
    };

    var pump = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIInputStreamPump); 
    pump.init(stream, -1, -1, 0, 0, false); 
    pump.asyncRead(dataListener, null); 
    
} catch (e){ 
    console.log("Error" + e.result + ": " + e.message); 
    return e; 
} return null;
};
```

Java (Server)

```java
ServerSocket providerSocket;
Socket connection = null;
ObjectOutputStream out;
ObjectInputStream in;
String message;
GoopirServer(){}
void run() {
    try{
        // Creating a server socket
        providerSocket = new ServerSocket(2222, 10);
        
        // Wait for connection
        System.out.println("Waiting for connection");
        connection = providerSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connection received from " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        
        // Get Input and Output streams
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        sendMessage("Connection successful");
        
        // The two parts communicate via the input and output streams
        do{
            try{
                message = (String)in.readObject();
                System.out.println("client>" + message);
                if (message.equals("bye"))
                    sendMessage("bye");
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException classnot){
                System.err.println("Data received in unknown format");
            }
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        // Closing connection
        try{
            in.close();
            out.close();
            providerSocket.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException){
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Sends a message to the plugin
 */
void sendMessage(String msg)
{
    try{
        out.writeObject(msg);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("server>" + msg);
    }
    catch(IOException ioException){
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firefox side seems to be correct (other than using a blocking call to write data), the issue is on the Java side. `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` are meant for exchanging serialized objects (in an undocumented format), not strings. And I think that `ObjectInputStream` expects to receive the magic number immediately, no wonder that it locks up without input. What you probably want to use are `BufferedReader` and `PrintWriter`. Also, you should use some separators for your messages, e.g. newlines (this would allow using `BufferedReader.readLine()`).

Comment: Hi Wladimir, I'd like you to take a look to this one: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318105/how-to-flush-a-socket-in-my-code#comment13283488_10318105

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding: `outstream.flush();` 
Right after: `outstream.write(outputData, outputData.length);`

Comment: It doesn't work. I've debugged the java app and it gets stuck at this line: "in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());"