# How to flush a socket in my code

Tags: javascript, sockets, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing through a socket from a FF add-on to a java server. I write several requests and the server seems to process them one-by-one. In contrast, the responses from the server are processed all at the same time.

I've tried flushing the out stream in the server but it does nothing. I don't understand what's going on.

I appreciate any help, thank you.

EDIT1: May be the add-on (client) is not flushing the input stream, is that possible? I'm using in the java server the out.println so the '\n' must flusht its output stream and the net library uses the write.flush(), but I don't see any other flush for the input.

EDIT2: Here is my code:

```
exports.main = function() {
    try  {
        // At first, we need a nsISocketTransportService
        var transportService =  
            Cc["@mozilla.org/network/socket-transport-service;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsISocketTransportService);  

        // Try to connect to localhost:2222
        var transport = transportService.createTransport(null, 0, "localhost", 6666, null);  

        var stream = transport.openInputStream(Ci.nsITransport.OPEN_UNBUFFERED,null,null); 
        var instream = Cc["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
            .createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableInputStream); 

        // Initialize
        instream.init(stream);
        var outstream = transport.openOutputStream(0, 0, 0);



        var dataListener = { 
            onStartRequest: function(request, context){},

            onStopRequest: function(request, context, status){
                instream.close();
                outstream.close();
            }, 

            onDataAvailable: function(request, context, inputStream, offset, count) { 
                var data = instream.read(count); 
                console.log(data);             
            }, 
        };

        var pump = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/input-stream-pump;1"]
                .createInstance(Ci.nsIInputStreamPump); 
        pump.init(stream, -1, -1, 0, 0, false); 
        pump.asyncRead(dataListener, null); 

        // Write data
        console.log("hi1");
        var outputData = "hi1\n";
        outstream.write(outputData, outputData.length);

        // Write data
        console.log("hi2");
        var outputData = "hi2\n";
        outstream.write(outputData, outputData.length);

    } catch (e){ 
        console.log("Error" + e.result + ": " + e.message); 
        return e; 
    } return null;
};
```

So, when I run it, I get:

```
Client > hi1
Client > hi2
Server > bye1
Server > bye2
```

And it should be:

```
Client > hi1
Server > bye1
Client > hi2
Server > bye2
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I added some code if you want to take a look.

Comment: You tagged this as Java, but I don't see any relation of your problem to Java. If you didn't tag it, we wouldn't have this conversation. I'm not an expert on JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! The server is written in Java but I think that is correct. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user1336939: Please don't edit your question to change it into a different question. If you need to ask a new question - ask a new question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought that it was a very similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the output stream synchronously, that means that no other JavaScript code can run while you do it. So receiving anything from the server while you are writing is impossible, incoming data is simply put into a buffer.

The other issue is that you are sending the next string without waiting for the response from server. Normally, you will be able to send off both of them before the server response arrives. You probably want to send the next string only when you receive the response to the previous one.

You probably want to use a send function like this one:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");

var toSend = ["hi1\n", "hi2\n"];

function sendNextString(outstream)
{
  if (!toSend.length)
    return;  // Nothing left to send

  var outputData = toSend.shift();
  console.log(outputData);
  var instream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
                           .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);
  instream.setData(outputData, outputData.length);

  NetUtil.asyncCopy(instream, outstream);
}
```

And you would call `sendNextString(outstream)` in your code after `pump.asyncRead()` as well as in `onDataAvailable`.

PS: From what I can tell, flushing the stream is *not* the issue here - you are using a non-buffering stream.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot. Although it doesn't work perfect, it seems that when I call sendNextString into the onDataAvailable, the server receives nothing. SOmething weird is happening, what do you think? (I updated the code in the question)

Comment: @user1336939: I think that you need to start debugging your code - you should be able to tell a little more than "something weird is happening".

Comment: But I debug the server and doesn't receive nothing. How can I debug the add-on? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a stream protocol, so you receive a stream of bytes. If you want packets, you got to implement your own protocol over TCP to be able to separate them. This topic is widely covered  on internet.

**Edit**

This is a common pitfall in socket programming. Most people do not understand at first that a TCP socket is a stream, not a message queue.

I mean, one call to "send" at one end of the socket **do not correspond necessarily** to one "receive" at the other end. The underlying layers can decide to group or split the bytes sent at will.

So you can have something like this:

- client sends "ABCD"
- client sends "EFGH"
- server receives "AB"
- server receives "CDEF"
- server receives "GH"

**This is a stream, not a message queue**. Think of it as a an infinite file you're reading in.

So, if you want to read strings out of a file, you need some way to separate them. It can be a delimiter, or you can prefix your strings by the string's length, or whatever.

Comment: But I've got no problem with the server: when it takes '\n' it flushes the stream. The client, otherwise, just prints the '\n'.I don't really know what you mean by implementing my own protocol.. If a give a opcode to each type of message, how can I detect that message at fly before it continues reading? Have you got any source I can look up? Thank you.